# facing issues in jquery event handler in 1.6 not in latest versions.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have a Jquery 1.6 version of the library, which make time to update. I am trying to implement Jquery event handler.

I have a group of divs which have a lot of buttons. The buttons keep getting added dynamically and I am trying to use  Jquerys event handler to keep track of the newly added buttons.

```
<div class="reason_badCode">
    <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_badCode"/>
    <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_badCode"/>
    <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_badCode"/>
</div>

<div class="reason_someOtherBadCode">
    <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_someOtherBadCode"/>
    <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_someOtherBadCode"/>
    <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_someOtherBadCode"/>
</div>
```

Now the combination of buttons and text boxes keep getting added.

```
$('div[class^="reason_"]').live('click', 'input[rel^="button_reason"]', function(event) {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

My JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/994ndy9c/

As can be seen in the fiddle, as soon as I typing in the text box, "clicked" is printed. I am not interested in my function to be called when I am typing. 
In the newer versions of Jquery, if I replace `live` with `on` it works perfectly.

Is there a way to make this work on jquery 1.6

Comment: why don't you just give a ID which is being added dynamically as well? Then set up an event listener to the button ID not the entire `input type`.

Comment: so what do you want? you don't want the `"clicked"` to be displayed when input box is checked?

Comment: @ShadowFiend I dont want my event handler to be called when I am typing text. It should be called only when a button is clicked. In newer versions of Jquery this works by replacing live with on

Comment: @ShadowFiend I guess he should just exclude the text input type. FYI try building eul's and blink dagger.

Comment: @ZombieChowder You mean doing this? 'input[idl^="button_reason"]' ? Wouldnt it be the same thing?

Comment: @user1692342 if you give this `ID` only to the buttons and not the **input text boxes**

Comment: I think you need `$('div[class^="reason_"] input[rel^="button_reason"]').live('click', function(event) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `live()` incorrectly. The method signature you're currently using matches what's required for delegated `on()` handlers, not `live()`.

Instead you need to select the dynamic element as the primary selector and call `live()` on it with the event name string and the handler function only, like this:

```js
$('input[rel^="button_reason"]').live('click', function(event) {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reason_badCode">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_badCode" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_badCode" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_badCode" />
</div>

<div class="reason_someOtherBadCode">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_someOtherBadCode" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_someOtherBadCode" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" rel="button_reason_someOtherBadCode" />
</div>
```

This being said I would ***strongly*** suggest that you upgrade the version of jQuery you're using so that you can utilise jQuery's `on()` method and other performance improvements. 1.6 is over 6 years out of date.

Comment: Thanks! Will try to update..Stuck with a legacy system :(

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('input[rel^="button_reason"]').click(function(event) {
        console.log("clicked");
   });
```

try this i will work